# Implementation of Google script for Moving row from one sheet to another sheet Implementation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script that moves the rows that are marked as "recorded" from one google spreadsheet to another one. My script is mostly based on this script [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337547/copy-one-row-from-one-sheet-to-another). However,upon executing the script ,it doesn't move all of the recorded rows from the source spreadsheet to target spreadsheet. I checked the value of dest array(dest.length and dest[0].length). but i can't find anything wrong beside not all the targets rows being captured and not all selected rows being removed. I am not familiar with javascript. If anyone can point me to the right direction, that would be great. Also, I don't know if it matters, but the source spreadsheet still uses the older version whereas the target spreadsheet uses newer version.

```
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Link1'); \\Source spreadsheet
  var ss = s.getSheetByName('Sheet28'); 
  var t = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Link2'); \\target spreadsheet
  var ts = t.getSheetByName('Sheet11');
  var data = ss.getRange(1,1, ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var dest = [];
  Logger.log(data.length)
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++ ){
    if ( data[i][22] == 'recorded' && data[i][22] !="") {
         dest.push(data[i]); 
       \\appending the array
         ss.deleteRow(i);
        \\delete the row
        }}
 Logger.log(dest.length);
 if (dest.length > 0  && dest[0].length >0}{
   ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1,dest.length,dest[0].length).setValues(dest);         
 }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a quick look at things. I think your code isn't working because when you delete a row, it alters the sheets structure, so the next delete will be wrong.

Example. You find a match in row 4 of your spreadsheet. Then row 4 is deleted in sheet. So row 5 becomes row 4 now
`i` gets increased by 1, so now it's on row 5 in your `data` array. If a match is found, Row 5 in sheet is deleted, when it should be Row 4 that's deleted.

The only thing I can think to solve this is do the matching first, then deleting afterwards, with something like this.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    if ( data[i][0] == 'recorded') {
           dest.push(data[i]); 


        }}

  for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++ ){
    if ( data[x][0] == 'recorded') {
      ss.deleteRow(x+1)  ;    

        }}
```

Perhaps this might work as a solution, it's untested.

```
function moveData(){

 var s = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Link1'); 
  var ss = s.getSheetByName('Sheet28'); 
  var t = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Link2'); 
  var ts = t.getSheetByName('Sheet11');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dest = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    if ( data[i][22] == 'recorded') {

         dest.push(data[i]); 


        }}

  for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++ ){
    if ( data[x][22] == 'recorded') {
      ss.deleteRow(x+1)  ;    

        }}

 if (dest.length > 0  && dest[0].length >0){
   ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1,dest.length,dest[0].length).setValues(dest);         
 }
}
```

EDIT

an after thought to solve the issue, would be perhaps. If the row is a match, delete the entry from both the `data` array AND the spreadsheet.

Then the `i` var could be kept in sync with row numbers.

Something along these lines, again untested

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    if ( data[i][22] == 'recorded') {

         dest.push(data[i]); 

         ss.deleteRow(i+1) ;
         delete data[i];
      i= i -1 ;
        }
   }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for quick responds, but error shows up as Cannot read property "22" from undefined. still figuring why.

Comment: array.splice() should be used instead, because delete would just remove the value, not the element.

Comment: What column is "recorded" found in?
splice could work :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way to solve your problem would be go from the bottom to the top.

```
for (var i =data.length; i > 1; i-- ){
    if ( data[i][22] == 'recorded' && data[i][22] !="") {
         dest.unshift(data[i]); 
       \\appending the array
         ss.deleteRow(i);
        \\delete the row
        }}
```

using unshift instead of push will keep the resulting array and its original order and i will always be pointing to an unaltered row of the spreadsheet.