# If matching content move to new sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script that looks through a list of suppliers, then needs to create a new sheet for each of them and import the information for that supplier into that sheet.

So far, I have the following:

```
function getData() {
  var masterSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() || SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");

  var supSS = masterSS.getSheetByName("Suppliers");
  masterSS.setActiveSheet(supSS)  
  var supSR = 2;
  var supNoRows = supSS.getLastRow() - 1;
  var supRange = supSS.getRange(supSR, 1, supNoRows, masterSS.getLastColumn());
  var supData = supRange.getValues();

  var orderSS = masterSS.getSheetByName("Orders");
  var orderData = orderSS.getRange("A2:AB").getValues();
  var templateSS = masterSS.getSheetByName("Template");

  supData.forEach(function(name) {
    var newSheet = masterSS.insertSheet(name, {template: templateSS});
    console.log(name)
  }); 
}
```

This is working as intended and is creating a sheet for each supplier listed on the Supplier sheet. I then need it to look through a range on a sheet called Orders, and if A2:A matches the supplier name used to create the new sheet, import that row to the newly created sheet.

I can't figure out quite how to get this working, as I would need to do it as each sheet is created. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to create a loop that will compare one column value to another, then if it matches push the array (row data) to the destination Sheet. You may want to check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13339507/5995040). This sample code copies value from sheet to another sheet inside a Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot.